# power bi: dynamic y-scale values based on data

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, scale, linechart

I'm building a dashboard in power bi and I have a dataset with a few percentages. There are several categories of data, but only one category is shown at a time. What I want to do is to dynamically change the y-axis values to reflect the data. At the moment, it's done automatically, but it makes the data look "worse" than it is, so I want to take the min and the max for that one category and add let's say another 10-20% to it, and use those values as the new scale. For example, if my data starts at 41% and ends at 63%, power bi automatically scales the chart between around 40% and 65%. I want to take these values, add 10% on each side and have the chart start at 30% up to 75% (roughly).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your visual is a line diagram then you can solve it by adding two additional measures to the plot:

```
y_top = MAX([pct_measure])+0,1
y_bottom = MIN([pct_measure])-0,1
```

Add both to the line diagram and then set their line widths to 0.

It's a variation of this:

[Power Bi Tips - Center X-axis on a line chart](https://powerbi.tips/2018/07/center-the-x-axis-on-a-line-chart/)